# ¿Porque se cae la conexión a una aplicación web, cuando entran muchos usuarios?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, codeigniter-3

Buenas a todos, 
Les comento el siguiente problema, he desarrollado un aplicativo web para una cadena de gimnasios, funcionaba correctamente con pocos usuarios conectados, ahora se usa en provincias y en total son mas de 150 usuarios conectados a la aplicación web, la aplicación se ha tornado muy lenta por momentos y claro genera molestias 
Se encontraba alojada en un servidor [vps hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting) plan Snappy 2000, debido a este problema se decidio pasar un plan Snappy 8000, el problema sigue por momentos se torna rapido y por momentos es lento.
La aplicación web esta realizada en Codeigniter 3, PHP, MySQL y AngularJS. 
Mi consulta es como puedo hacer para solucionar este problema, ya que se ha estado pensando emigrar a un plan de Amazon, pero no se si esto solucionara el problema, esta la primera aplicación que realizo para muchos usuarios.

Saludos, gracias de antemano

Comment: Pues pueden ser muchas cosas, lo primero que podriamos pensar es que sea problema con la base de datos, debes de poner un monitoreo de como esta trabajando la bd, quiza tengas muchas consultas muy pesadas o quiza solo haya un par que te esten ocasionando estos problemas de lentitud

Comment: es muy difícil contestar esta pregunta sin conocer bien todos los detalles. deberias comprobar la performance de la base, hacer un profiling de las consultas que haces a la base, quiza tengas que poner la base en otra maquina separada (esto ayudara bastante)... lo que tienes que hacer es perfil de cada parte y ver donde estan los cuellos de botella y solucionarlos uno x uno. Ademas no es posible aumentar el hardware para siempre, en algun punto deberas hacer tu app pueda funcionar con mas de un web server. la escalabilidad se obtiene por diseño mucho mas que por optimizar algoritmos

Comment: Pues esto es muy muy amplio, puede ser la Base de Datos, puede ser el como haces tus consultas, puede ser la metodología de tu programación, pero bien yo creo que puedes empezar por ir monitorizando tus peticiones y demás. Ahora por otra parte, Felicidades por el éxito de tu aplicativo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, como puedo monitorizar las peticiones a mi BD, existe alguna herramienta o una forma de detectar esos cuellos de botella.

Comment: hola, bienvenid@ a la familia de SOes, te recomiendo darle una lectura a: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask saludos :D

Comment: por cierto, revisa esto: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9881

Comment: y también MySQL Workbench: http://mysqlworkbench.org/2014/04/whats-new-in-mysql-workbench-6-1/